# How to define null object value for key-value pair in yaml in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, key-value

This is how my configuration looks now:

- this is a key-value = map configuration
- key is a number as an ID
- value is an object as a person
- for the 3rd and 4th I wanted to setup null as person object

```
setup:
    identifications:
        1:
            name: John
            age: 50
        2:
            name: Sarah
            agen: 40
        3: null
        4:
        5:
            name: Joe
            age: 20
```

These are the java classes:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "setup")
public class Setup {

    private Map<Integer, Person> identifications;
    
    getter/setter
    
    public static class Person {
    
        private String name;
        private Integer age;
        
        getters/setters
    
    }

}
```

After starting spring boot application, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [my.package.Setup.Person]
```

If I delete the 3rd and 4th (the null ones), the application starts successfully.
So it has a problem to insert a key into the map with null value.
Is it possible somehow? I know that maps can have null values. But I don't know how to specify null object as a value in yml.

Comment: YAML spec says `null` *should* be loaded as null value but since it isn't, try `!!null` instead.

Comment: yes I also red that spec, and tried with !!null but didn't help :(

Comment: What happens if you provide `!!null`? If you can't get that to work, you probably need to go the hacky path of creating a converter from `String` to `Person` which converts `"null"` to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

- I assume, you don't want to leave those 2 keys all together from `yaml` for documentation purposes or something because leaving them have the same effect on the created map
- See this issue. Springs `YamlProcessor` translates null and empty to `""`. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8873
- If you define a static method like this in person, it will work

```
    public static Person of(String value) {
      if (value.trim().isEmpty())
        return null;
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```